# Application which retrieves data from Server only if there is new data available

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a design question. I've made an app which retrieves data from Google App Engine Datastore and displays it to user.

I would like to accomplish retrieval of the data only if data inside datastore was added/deleted/updated. For now I was thinking to retrieve data from server after user starts application for the first time and store the data inside SQLite database and give user a button to check for new data. After he clicks the button all data would be downloaded again and I would compare that data with records inside database. That seems to me a little bit too much of work for my App but I am a beginner so maybe this is how it's done :)

My goal is something like this:

1. User starts application for the first time
2. All data is automatically downloaded to his device and stored to SQLite database
3. Each time when application is started, it checks for new data in datastore. If there is new data, it downloads that data.

What is currently the best practice in cashing data on device and downloading new data only if there is new data available? Is there a way to check if datastore is changed and to download only data which is changed?

I hope my question is not to confusing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can use for this is push messages, take a look at GCM:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html